# Usage of a helper within zend partialloop

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am using the Zend Framework library / Framework

At some point I need to give an array of texts ( with a given objectKey ) to the partialloop helper.

Now in the partialLoop view I would like to use Zend Translate.

Now I understand that Zend Translate isn't accessibly true the objectKey, but is there a way to use Zend Translate here and even use a helper ... ?

Thanks in advance,
math

Answer (score 1):

Solution is putting the translate in the [Zend Framework and Zend Translations](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4513-Zend-Framework-and-Translation)

Answer (score 1):

The translate() view helper will still be available within the view script of a partial loop as it assues you have put a Zend_Translate object into the registry with the key 'Zend_Translate'

Regards,

Rob...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this . .This way the "$translate" object is available across all the views and hence to viewhelpers.

**Bootsrap.php**

```
protected function _initTranslate()
{
    $translate = new Zend_Translate(array(
        'adapter' => 'gettext',
        'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/locale/en-US.mo',
        'locale'  => 'en'
    ));

    Zend_Registry::set('translate', $translate);
    Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);

    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->translate = $translate;
}
```

Hope it helps!